# How can I import db table from an excel file?

Tags: database, excel, visual-studio, import

I have created a database on visual studio 2010. I want to load the table from an excel sheet because there are lots of data. How can I import it?

**Note:** In many sources, people use Sql Server Management Studio, but I do not have it so I need to make it on Visual Studio or another way. It can be just clicking on Visual Studio or executing a query etc.

Comment: SQL server management Studio is free isn't it?

Comment: Because of company security policy, I cannot create a db in sql management studio

Comment: I don't quite understand the situation, but if you have a way to visually view the database and make changes to it, and the data in the excel sheet is in the same order as in the database, you can usually just copy everything from the excel sheet and paste it in the database (might take some time though if there is a lot of data)